# Directive element multiplies on window scroll

Tags: jquery, angularjs, element, scrollto

I have a dynamic web application that changes page views on a button click. One page I have is a scrolling page that "spies" on the sections, similarly to Bootstrap's scroll spy. It works as expected when there's only one page.

If there is more than one page, the element gets added on every time I navigate to one of these scrolling pages, but only in the scrolling function. (i.e. page 1: element = element, page 2: element = element * 2, page 3: element = element *3, so on). This breaks the logic in the scrolling function and produces a `TypeError: $(previous).offset().top` is undefined.

Here is the view:

```
<div id="scroll-container" class="row" scroll-spy>
<div class="container sidebar grid_4">
    <div class="well">
        <nav class="page-nav">
            <ul class="">
                <li class="spy" ng-repeat="group in currentPage.Group" data-spy="{{group.id}}" >
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" role="link" ng-bind-html="group.Title.html" ng-click="scrollTo(group.id)"><span class="right-arrow"></span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container content grid_12">
    <h2 ng-bind-html="currentPage.Title.html"></h2>
    <div class="group row" ng-repeat="group in currentPage.Group" id="{{group.id}}">
        <h3 ng-bind-html="group.Title.html"></h3>
        <p class="lead" ng-repeat="item in group.SimpleText" ng-bind-html="item.html"></p>
        <hr class="group-divider"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the directive:

```
define(['../../../directives/application/MainDirective'], function(directives){
directives.directive('scrollSpy',['$rootScope','$state','$stateParams','$location','$anchorScroll','$window','$compile',function($rootScope,$state,$stateParams,$location,$anchorScroll,$window,$compile){
    return{
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: function($scope){
            $scope.spies = [];
        },
        terminal: false,
        link: function($scope,pElement,attrs){

            var api = $scope.$parent;
            var trace = api.trace;
            var elem = pElement;
            var sidebar = pElement.find(".sidebar");
            var offset = sidebar.offset();
            var topPadding = 50;
            var links = [];

            var listener = $scope.$watch('spies',function(spies){ 
                elem.find("li.spy").eq(0).addClass("active");
                links = elem.find("li.spy").click(function(event){ 
                    var spy = $(this); 
                    $(this).toggleClass("active"); 
                    $location.hash(spy.attr("data-spy")); 
                    $anchorScroll();
                });
            });

            angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function(e){
                var current = {}, spy = {}, previous = {};

                links.each(function(index){
                    previous = index > 0 ? $("#"+links.eq(index - 1).attr("data-spy")) : null;
                    if(!previous) current = $(this);
                    else if($(previous).offset().top + $(previous).outerHeight() < window.scrollY) current = $(this);
                });

                links.removeClass("active");
                current.addClass("active");

                if($($window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                    sidebar.stop().animate({
                        marginTop: $($window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                    });
                } else  {
                    sidebar.stop().animate({
                        marginTop: 0
                    });
                }
            });

            $scope.$on('$destroy',function(){
                trace("destroying");
            });
        }
    };
}]);
});
```

I know that `$window` 'exists' outside of angular, and I've tried `$apply()`, but maybe I'm not using it correctly? Does this scroll function need it's own service? Any help is appreciated.